# Angular service unable to execute function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function loadUserCredentials() {
    var token = new Object();
    token.token = window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/checkTokenValid",token).then(function(result){
        console.log(result.data.success);
        if(result.data.success){
            useCredentials();
        }
    });
};
```

This `loadCredentials()` is loaded everytime the page refresh, I'm checking if it is authenticated at my `angular.run`

```
controlApp.run(function ($location, $rootScope,controlProvider){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function(event,next,nextParems){
        if (!controlProvider.isAuthenticated()){
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    })
});
```

I think this is running before `loadCredentials` complete, so I always get login page. Is there any way I can delay the `angular.run`? So that I can have my `loadCredentials` to check is the user having the valid token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that by $timeout :

```
controlApp.run(function ($location, $rootScope, controlProvider, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, nextParems) {
        $timeout(function () {
            if (!controlProvider.isAuthenticated()) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        }, 500);
    })
});
```